# ERROR in Node does not exist: C:/projects/ma/CustomerPortal-master/node_modules/ngx-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

[error attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Epn2.png)

getting above error on

> npm start or ng build

Comment: Can you provide your package.json and the code for the module you're importing ngx-smart-table to?